# WCF Task based service consumption in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.android

I was refactoring WPF project to add support for android, I have a PCL project for consuming WCF service. The same code works fine for WCF, but generates error in Android application.

Here is the service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMessage
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<string> GetMessages(string msg);
}
```

and its implementation:

```
public class Message : IMessage
{
    public async Task<string> GetMessages(string msg)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            return "Return from Server : " + msg;
        });
        return await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

A helper class to create ClientBase<>:

```
public class Proxy : ClientBase<IMessage>
{
    public Proxy()
    {
    }
    public Proxy(string endpointConfigurationName) :
        base(endpointConfigurationName)
    {
    }
}
```

And this is how the service is consumed:

```
var client = new Proxy("BasicHttpBinding_IMessage");
HelloServer = "Waiting for the result";
HelloServer = await client.Channel.GetMessages(Hello);
```

WPF application works with no problem, but Android generates an error:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException:
Deserializing type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[[System.String, mscorlib,
Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]'.
Expecting state 'EndElement'. Encountered state 'Text' with name '' with namespace ''. (1,141)`
```

Comment: Your code is wrong. You can't pass a `Task<T>` thru a wire. Remove that and create a proper service.

Comment: @HighCore This code is based on [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/613678/Task-based-Asynchronous-Operation-in-WCF), and it works well in WPF and Store applications, exception is generated with mono.

Comment: I'm guessing that Xamarin does not support using Tasks on the client side. Try using Begin/End pairs and wrapping them into a Task manually.

Comment: @StephenCleary Hi, can you show how as the answer?

Comment: @MerdanGochmuradov Hi, Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @Marshall: I wrote it up in a blog post [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-wcf-today-and-tomorrow.html).